# Image upload to Heroku App

Tags: javascript, heroku, amazon-s3, ssh, web-deployment

I am currently investigating a way to upload Images to a Heroku repo where I have a python-application that takes in the images, has them classified and saves the results in a .csv file.
The Images can be selected for upload via a website that uses Javascript and HTML.

My Question now is, how would I best enable the upload from the website to the Heroku App?

Bearing in mind that the Frontend is currently running on my local machine and that I want to use Heroku as a Backend to take in either Images or Strings.

Will I need an SSH-connection to a separate Web server? Will I need to use Amazon S3?

Not looking for a complete Solution to my problem per se, but if someone could point me in the right direction as to what I will need to solve my problem that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* upload an image to Heroku however there two problems with that

1. Heroku router times out requests after 30 seconds which means that if your users have a spotty connection and/or huge files the upload will fail
2. Heroku's ephemeral filesystem means that you must process this file in your web process because workers run on different dynos and don't have access to your web dyno filesystem. So that's another strike at 30 seconds timeout.

Your best bet is to have your users upload their files directly to s3 from their browsers. We had a good experience with filestack.com js widget, but there are other ways.

Your page will then ping your backend with this newly uploaded file's s3 url. The backend will launch an asynchronous job using Heroku worker to process it.

This neatly solves all issues with timeouts and blocking your web dynos.

Comment: Alright, thanks ;)
Now I at least got a few more things that I can look into :)

I was also considering using a WebSocket on a Heroku node.js server and sending the pictures through to that from my client using a base64 encoding. The pictures don't have to be too big (244,  244) so I figured that might be an easy alternative, do you think this might be possible?
Also, should I create a separate thread for this question?

Comment: Actually nvm, I already figured that this might not be the best way to go.
I'll be working on setting up the suggested solution using s3 - thanks again.